# Pretty new to Linux

Tags: drivers, hardware

As the title suggest i'm fairly new to Linux and i'm curious how it works with drivers.

NVIDIA Graphics worked out for me after some research, but I don't know about the rest of the machine. Coming from Windows my mindset is installing all kinds of drivers.

I'll post my hardware down below and hope someone can tell me if I'm missing drivers or that all is installed.

```
    cpu:                                                            
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 2680 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 2784 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 1253 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 1346 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 2333 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 1258 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 1871 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 3296 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 1266 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 1250 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 1442 MHz
                       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz, 1239 MHz
keyboard:
                       Logitech G710 Gaming Keyboard
mouse:
                       Logitech G3 (MX518) Optical Mouse
graphics card:
                       nVidia VGA compatible controller
sound:
                       nVidia Audio device
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller
                       Blue Microphones Yeti Stereo Microphone
storage:
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset sSATA Controller [AHCI mode]
                       Samsung Electronics Non-Volatile memory controller
network:
  ens4                 Intel Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter
network interface:
  ens4                 Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
disk:
  /dev/sdb             SAMSUNG HD753LJ
  /dev/sdc             SAMSUNG HD103UJ
  /dev/sda             Crucial_CT512MX1
  /dev/nvme0n1         Samsung Electronics Disk
partition:
  /dev/sdb1            Partition
  /dev/sdc1            Partition
  /dev/sda1            Partition
  /dev/sda2            Partition
  /dev/nvme0n1p1       Partition
  /dev/nvme0n1p2       Partition
  /dev/nvme0n1p3       Partition
  /dev/nvme0n1p4       Partition
  /dev/nvme0n1p5       Partition
  /dev/nvme0n1p6       Partition
usb controller:
                       ASMedia ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
                       VIA VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset USB xHCI Host Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #4
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 3
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DMI2
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 3
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 1
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #5
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #1
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset LPC Controller
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 1
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #8
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
                       Intel Hub
                       VIA Hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Intel Hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
  /dev/lp0             Parallel controller
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Hot Plug
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 ERROR Registers
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset SMBus Controller
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 Thermal Control
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Global Broadcast
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Global Broadcast
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 2 ERROR Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 0
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 I/O APIC
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCIe Ring Interface
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 2 Thermal Control
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset SPSR
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 RAS, Control Status and Global Errors
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Address Map, VTd_Misc, System Management
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 ERROR Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 Thermal Control
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Channel 0/1 Broadcast
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 3 ERROR Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 0
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0 Thermal Control
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 VCU
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Channel 2/3 Broadcast
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 3 Thermal Control
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1
                       Yuan Yuan Enterprise Unclassified device
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 VCU
                       Intel C610/X99 series chipset MEI Controller #1
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCIe Ring Interface
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers
                       Intel Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1
                       Serial controller
                       Blue Microphones Yeti Stereo Microphone
                       Microsoft Controller
                       Logitech G710 Gaming Keyboard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to AppCenter and check the "Installed" tab. There you'll have every driver you need to install on the Drivers section.

Linux already have most drivers inside the kernel so you get them by default. However sometimes you need to install some extra drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Install the Ubuntu Software Manager:
   sudo apt install software-properties-gtk
2. Open it: in the Applications menu, it appears as "Software & Updates" and go to the "Additional Drivers" tab.

If you have any uninstalled drivers, they should show in there. But if you see any other drivers for NVidia, don't install them since you already have your NVidia card working.

Comment: Right now you don't need to install anything. Appcenter already has a section dedicated to the drivers :)

Comment: It only says Nvidia indeed, so we good :D Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Maccer, where is that option on AppCenter? I can't find it on mine.

Comment: Check my answer above. If you still can't see it, it may be because you don't need any extra drivers.